# How to cancel Retrofit2 Rxjava2

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I created a request to the youtube api search.
When a request is sent, requests before it must be canceled and no updates are made to the cache.

I used a CompositeDisposable to add each Disposable and clear it when creating a new request.

However, as I noticed that the previous request was not canceled, the cache was still updated.

```
   disposable.clear();
   disposable.add(Network.search(nextPageToken, (isSearchingOnline() ? mFilterText : ""), item.topicId, listener));


public static Disposable search(String nextPageToken, String query, String topicId, String publishedAfter, OnYoutubeSearchListener listener) {
        YParams yParam = new YParams(50, Constants.YOUTUBE_DEVERLOPE_KEY, "snippet", "video", nextPageToken, "10", query, publishedAfter, topicId);
        if (cacheData.containsKey(yParam)) {
            if (listener != null) {
                for (Map.Entry<YParams, List<VideoBean>> entry : cacheData.entrySet()) {
                    YParams key = entry.getKey();
                    List<VideoBean> value = entry.getValue();
                    if (key.equals(yParam)) {
                        listener.onReturnPageToken(key.getNextPageToken());
                        listener.onSuccess(value);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return new CompositeDisposable();
        }
        return Network.getYoutubeApi().search(50, Constants.YOUTUBE_DEVERLOPE_KEY, "snippet", "video", nextPageToken, "10", "", publishedAfter, "")
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .flatMap((Function<Videos, ObservableSource<Videos>>) videos -> {
                    if (videos.items.size() > 0) {
                        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                        for (Videos.Item i : videos.items) {
                            builder.append(i.id.videoId);
                            builder.append(",");
                        }
                        yParam.setNextPageToken(videos.nextPageToken);
                        if (listener != null) {
                            listener.onReturnPageToken(videos.nextPageToken);
                        }
                        return Network.getYoutubeApi().getVideosDetail(Constants.YOUTUBE_DEVERLOPE_KEY, builder.substring(0, builder.length() - 1), "snippet,contentDetails,statistics");
                    }
                    return Observable.fromArray(Videos.EMPTY_VIDEOS);
                })
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .map(new Function<Videos, List<VideoBean>>() {
                    @Override
                    public List<VideoBean> apply(Videos videos) {
                        List<VideoBean> list = new ArrayList();
                        for (Videos.Item bean : videos.items) {
                            list.add(new VideoBean(bean.id.videoId, bean.snippet.title, bean.snippet.description, bean.snippet.thumbnails._default.url, bean.snippet.channelTitle, bean.contentDetails.duration, bean.snippet.publishedAt, 0));
                        }
                        return list;
                    }
                })
                .subscribe(items -> {
                    if (items != null && items.size() > 0) {
                        cacheData.put(yParam, items);
                    }
                    if (listener != null) {
                        listener.onSuccess(items);
                    }
                }, throwable -> {
                    if (listener != null) {
                        listener.onFailed(throwable);
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: Please check my answer hope this may help to you.

Comment: Did you find the answer? I also wonder how this can be solved. d.dispose() not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to cancel Retrofit2 Rxjava2 in android?

You have to keep a reference to the `Disposable` object and call `dispose()` on it.